# How to capture the SOAP request send by the java app

Tags: java, spring, soap

I have a REST API written in java and spring which makes a backend call to a SOAP service. The SOAP web service code are packaged in a 3rd party jar. So don't have access to change the code. But I can change the SOAP service endpoint by setting a env variable.

How can I capture the raw SOAP request sent by the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the SOAP Request by using number of tools.

I would suggest either use TCPMonitor (https://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html) or wiresharks (https://www.wireshark.org/).

TCPMonitor acts like a proxy (So your endpoint should point to TCPMonitor), and it will relay the message back to your service.

Wireshark is a network protocol analyser. It captures all the TCP/UDP packets (which includes the HTTP as well). You just have to capture the packets. No modifications from server and client ends required. You can then filter the HTTP/HTTPS packets to look for your requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a network packet Analyser such as [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) or [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture packets sent specifically to your 'endpoint'.

**ALTERNATIVELY**

You can write a tiny proxy to capture requests on a local port and forward them to the actual endpoint and route response after printing it to sys-out. You, in that case, will specify the proxy as the endpoint to your program.

I am not sure of any existing proxy which does that, but I think [haproxy will not](https://serverfault.com/questions/524525/logging-entire-post-body-with-haproxy).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you can use [ProxyTrace](http://pocketsoap.com/tcptrace/pt.aspx), [PocketSoap](http://pocketsoap.com/pocketsoap/), and other [PocketSoap.com](http://pocketsoap.com/) tools.